# How to prevent `diff -rq` from showing newly created files, when comparing the different versions of a folder?

Tags: diff, file-comparison

I am doing `diff -rq` to check the difference between 2 folders (`A` and `B`). I don't want to know if folder `A` has any new files because that's expected. How do I ensure that this information doesn't come up?

Comment: I guess instead of using `diff -rq` you could perform a `find . -type f ...` in B, and then compare those files against the same files in A.

Comment: I thought that "new files" are related somehow to date (files that were created after certain time). If you just want to ignore files from A that aren't in B (as the accepted answer does), why not just run `grep -v "Only in A:"` on your `diff -rq A B` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment now that I'm at an actual keyboard:

The only way to do what you want is to diff files individually. We can combine `find` and `xargs` to do that, something like this:

```
(cd B && find . -type f -print0) | xargs -0 -IPATH diff -q A/PATH B/PATH
```

This produces a list of all files in B relative to the top directory, and the uses xargs to run a series of `diff -q` commands comparing the file in B to the same path in A.

When the directories have identical content, it produces no output and the return code is `0`:

```
$ (cd B && find . -type f -print0) | xargs -0 -IPATH diff -q A/PATH B/PATH
$ echo $?
0
```

When there are differences, `diff -q` prints a message to the console, and the return code is `123`:

```
$ (cd B && find . -type f -print0) | xargs -0 -IPATH diff -q A/PATH B/PATH
Files A/./dir2/dir3/file1 and B/./dir2/dir3/file1 differ
$ echo $?
123
```